# QlikSense Saas - Cumulative YTD without using RangeSum & Above

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, set-analysis

Trying to create the Measure below Cumulative that is basically a cumulative YTD calculation applied to the Amount column (Amount = Count(ORDER_ID)).

That print screen was taken from the desktop app, that natively integrates a cumulative option within the graph components. That's not an option in my context where I need to use the Saas version.

Qlik Desktop - Cumulative YTD

[image: 1]

I've seen many articles in the community that suggest to use a combination of rangesum and above but I'm trying to avoid that.

Coming from the Power BI world, I was used to calculate it with a Calculate(Count(ORDER_ID), ALL(Date), DatesYTD(Date), Date<= max(Date)). The All() removes all context filtering to the measure, and we then filter according to what we need, applying a set varibale max(Date), to ensure a cumulative calculation of the amount month to month.

I haven't found yet a good equivalent of the All() Power BI function that actually removes the context filtering in a pivot table/graph (here the breakdown by the month dimension), to allow us a to then apply a different filtering for instance in our case on a cumulative YTD basis.

I've tried something with total() in my set analysis, see below, but it's not working:

Count ( Distinct total< [Date.autoCalendar.Year], Date> ${<RECORD_TYPE = {'Declared Transactions'}, Date >=${"=YearStart(MAX(Date))"}, Date<=${"=MAX(Date)"} >} ORDER_ID )

which gives that result:

[Qlik Saas - Wrong cumulative YTD measure attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1rEHC.png)

Basically that's my problem:
[Qliksense documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxI07.png)

Comment: Im not familiar with PowerBI but `All() removes all context filtering` means just "ignore all selections/filters" applied in the app?

Comment: @StefanStoichev, that's correct. ALL() ignores all timeline/selection filters as well as any dimension filters within the graph/pivot table.

Comment: It this case you can use `1` state in the expressions. e.g. `sum( {1} Sales)` will calculate `Sales` by ignoring all filters/selections. The default state (that is omitted) is `$` `Sum(Sales)` == `Sum( {$} Sales)`

Comment: @StefanStoichev, I thought of using the {1} in the set analysis. But it doesn't remove the filtering by dimension within the pivot table though. With that method, I'm not going to be able to get the cumulative YTD for each month, it'll just disregard any user selection filters. I though of using the Total() function, but then I get the opposite problem, I get the whole total in each month.

Comment: just added a picture of my problem at the bottom. Basically Qlik documentation says: sum ({1} Sales) returns total sales for the document, disregarding selections but not the dimension. That last part of the sentence "but not the dimension" is my problem.

Comment: tried this but not working: Count ( Total <[Date.autoCalendar.Year], Date> Distinct {$< RECORD_TYPE = {'Declared Transactions'}, Date = {"< $(Max(Date))"}>} ORDER_ID )